# How to make a terminal console (terminal emulator) in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, pyqt5, terminal-emulator

I am building an application in Python, with a graphical user interface in PyQt5. I need to insert some sort of "Terminal Console" in the application. The user can start a batch file by clicking a button, and should see the output appear in a text field.

At this moment, I use the following approach. When the user presses a button, the program will start the batch script (say "myBat.bat"). The standard output gets extracted and written to a QTextEdit widget.

[image]

This works great, but there are two serious problems.

---

**(PROBLEM 1) The output is shown at the end of the batch execution..**

And that's sometimes really painful. Especially if the bat-file takes some time to execute, the user will get the impression that everything freezes.

**(PROBLEM 2) The user cannot give commands..**

Some bat-files require user input. I have no idea on how to do this.

**(PROBLEM 3) When the batch file is finished, it's over..**

Sometimes the user wants to keep giving commands to the terminal, even when the batch file has finished. For example a simple `dir` command, to list out the files in a directory. Anything should be possible.

To summarise everything, I just need to make a functional terminal console inside my application.

There is a guy who ported QTermWidget to PyQt4. This is the link:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtermwidget/?source=typ_redirect  . Unfortunately his code is not compiled for Windows (I'm working on a Windows 10 machine). And his port is made for PyQt4. My entire application is written in PyQt5. There are reasons why I cannot go back to PyQt4.

Another guy made this software:
https://bitbucket.org/henning/pyqtermwidget/overview  . Also very interesting, but no Windows support.

---

Please help..

**EDIT :**

This is the code I'm currently running:

```
    ###############################################
    ### This function gets called when the user ###
    ### pushes the button                       ###
    ###############################################

    def myBatFunction(self):

        # 1. Call the proper batch file
        p = Popen("C:\\..\\myFolder\\myBat.bat" , cwd=r"C:\\..\\myFolder", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        p.wait()
        if p.returncode == 0:
            pass
        else:
            return

        # 2. Capture the standard out stream from the batch file
        msg = stdout.decode("utf-8")
        errMsg = stderr.decode("utf-8")

        self.myTextArea.setText(msg + errMsg)

    ###############################################
```

**EDIT :** If you think this is a duplicate question, please verify first if the other question offers a solution to Windows 10 users, and works with PyQt5 :-)

Comment: How are you executing the batch file?

Comment: According to [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout), your `p` has a `.stdout` attribute, and you can read from it in a loop. The reads will block until some of the bat file output is available. This may be the way to do the real-time output updates you are looking for.

Comment: So I should make some kind of loop that keeps reading from the p.stdout, and add the string to the text area?

Comment: For the output problem, you can stream output from Popen using the process outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate/17698359#17698359)

Comment: Please can you publish the PyQt5 terminal lib on Github?

Answer (score 1):

In your code `p.wait()` is the point of synchronization with the opened process. After that line the external process is finished. So you need to read `p.stout` in a loop **before** that line. Check the following example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(["C:\\..\\myFolder\\myBat.bat"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
with p.stdout:
    for line in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
        print line,
p.wait() # wait for the subprocess to exit
```

Note that `bufsize` should be `1` to suppress buffering.

Comment: Hi Kirill,
Thank you very much for your suggestion. How exactly would I loop through `p.stdout` before the `p.wait()` command? I mean, how do I know when to stop looping?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @K.Mulier I have added the example for python2.